# why adding tocloft package causes tex4ht not to generate a table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, tocloft

texlive 2014 on Linux mint 17.

This MWE does not generate a table of contents in the HTML file generated by htlatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}  %if this line is commented, then toc will show up
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
  \section{sec1}
  some text 1
  \section{sec2}
  some text 2
\end{document}
```

if `tocloft` is *not* used, then toc will show  up in html.

command to compile is

```
htlatex foo.tex
```

Then view the file `foo.html` in same folder to see the missing toc.

This came up when I was trying to change the font size of the toc and used this package, which works ok with pdflatex, then noticed the toc is missing in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `tex4ht` and `tocloft` redefine table of contents mechanism, so they clash each other. Because you can't use `tocloft` settings with `tex4ht` anyway, it is best to to disable `tocloft`. From fast look at `tocloft` source code, it seems that we can use `\if@cftnctoc` conditional for this purpose, when set to true, no redefinitions take place. Fortunately, all redefinitions are done in `\AtBeginDocument` commands, which seems is time when `.4ht` files are loaded. So, we can introduce `tocloft.4ht` file, with really simple contents:

```
\@cftnctoctrue
\endinput
```

Value of `\if@cftnctoc` is set to true. This file is loaded before `tocloft` redefinition commands check for value of `\if@cftnctoc`, so no redefinitions take place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. Ok, Will enter this a low priority bug in tex4ht database so it does not get lost. Thanks.